# C++ Add to the end of array

Tags: c++, arrays

I created a pointer to pointer to a dynamic vector, is called "list".

```
   listaFiguras::listaFiguras(){
    numElements = 0;
    list = new figuraGeom* [numElements];

}
```

Here is my class too:

```
class listaFiguras {

    //Atributos
    int numElements;
    figuraGeom **list;

public :

    //Constructor sin parametros
    listaFiguras();

    //Destructor
    ~listaFiguras();

    //Sets y Gets
    void setnumElementos(int);
    virtual void setLista(figuraGeom**);

    int getnumElementos();
    virtual figuraGeom* getLista();

    //Vaciar lista
    void vaciarLista();

    //Añadir elemento
    void anyadirElemento(figuraGeom *);

};
```

Now I have to create a method called anyadirElemento but do not understand how I can do this:

Take as a parameter a pointer to figuraGeom, and added at the end of the dynamic array pointed to by list.

I got this:

```
void listaFiguras :: anyadirElemento (figuraGeom * parameter) {



}
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to be using `std::vector` instead of a fixed-length array (which is what you have in `list` right now)?

Comment: Yes Im going to edit it

Comment: There is an error in your code: read about the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). If you can use C++11, using `std::unique_ptr<figuraGeom*[]> list;` would alleviate the need for using a destructor and you automatically prevent copies and assignments as well.

Comment: Oh I didnt knew that! Thank you!

Comment: @devtreat - You have virtual functions, meaning that this class is designed to be derived from.  Therefore your destructor should be virtual also, but it isn't.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is virtual now :D Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler if instead of the dynamically allocated array you would use `std::vector<figuraGeom *>`

You have to keep the current position in the array that to know where to add a new value. For example let assume that you defined such data member of the class

```
int position;
```

and initialized it to zero some way (for example in a constructor of the class)

Then the function could look the following way provided that the array may not be reallocated

```
void listaFiguras :: anyadirElemento (figuraGeom * parameter)
{
   if ( position < numElements ) list[position++] = parameter;
}
```

So I would define data members of the class as

```
class listaFiguras {

    //Atributos
    int numElements;
    int position;
    figuraGeom **list;
//...
```

If you are allowed to enlarge the initially allocated array then the function should reallocate it each time if position is equal to numElements where numElements also will be changed or you should keep another variable that will store the current size of the array.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple dynamic array is define as follow:

- array size
- pointer to array

You need to know how many elements are currently in the array to be able to use them; and when adding/removing an element you simply create another array with one less or one more element (which involves copying the old array into the new).

*Note: this is extremely inefficient adding an element is O(N) where N is the number of elements already in the array but it's also very simple, in real code use `std::vector<T>` which performs addition at the end in amortized O(1).*

Comment: Yes, here I got it, but I dont have to use std::vector, I have to use dynamic array

Comment: @devtreat: I know, thus the advise of keeping track of the size and copying when adding or removing elements.